# OK, I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my powerbook g4, 1.33 17". Can I partition and set dual boot mac os x? (with out losing the ubuntu)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, powerpc

So get this, I find lots of Dual Booting help if I install the Mac os X software first, and I even have the original bootcamp disks and such, but I have Ubuntu working perfectly on the machine as my only operating system and it wasnt exactly simple. IS there a way I can partition the drive from ubuntu and dual (re-install) the Mac os x?

Comment: I just dont want to lose the ubuntu boot ! but would like to have the mac os x choice too ! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think bootcamp will help - that is for intel-based Macs as far as I know.

I have not done this so I'll suggest a method but you will need to be careful not to overwrite your Ubuntu partitions.

Use GParted to resize your partitions to make room for OS-X. You will need about 10 GB.

Now boot with OS-X DVD. Once you get to a desktop, you can run Disks from a menu to setup an HFS+ partition in your free space for OS-X.

OS-X should offer to install into this partition.